# Preventing select query on ForeignKey when the primary key is known

Tags: python, sql, django

to insert a row to a table that has a one-to-one relationship, you would do this in Django:

```
mypk=2   # Comes from the POST request
model=MyModel(myField="Hello", myForeignModel=ForeignModel.objects.get(pk=mypk))
model.save()
```

This will cause a SELECT query followed by an INSERT query.

However, the SELECT query isn't really necessary as it will be the `mypk` that is inserted into the foreign key field. Is there a way to get Django to just insert the primary key without doing a SELECT?

Secondly, are there concurrency issues here (in the event that the primary key would change before the user submits the request). If so, how are these dealt with?

Comment: Seems like you'd want to be loading `mypk` prior to this anyway to validate that the form values are valid, that the user has permission, etc.

Comment: mypk is stored in Javascript and is sent by an AJAX request. All users have permission and it's protected from CSRF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#database-representation):

> Behind the scenes, Django appends `"_id"` to the field name to create its database column name.

Simply set `myForeignModel_id` to the FK value.

Comment: Perfect. Tested it with the SQL profiler and the SELECT query is gone.